# have the data of rows on columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset like the first table that has a gender value for each row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFjsa.png)

I want an output table like the second screen shot that gender is not a column. And all the data for the rest of the columns are separated between "Female" and "male" with two main column with an aggregated total column. how can I get this in pandas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSDxQ.png)

Comment: Warm welcome to SO! Please help us to help you. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then update your question and provide us your two example directly in the question text without using image links. Don't use images but text (formated as code).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`pandas.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) which is similar to how it is in Excel. The code below will give you what is required. I have renamed blanks (`NaN`) to `0` here.

```
table = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    values='score',
    index=['job'],
    columns=['gender'],
    aggfunc=np.sum)

table.columns.name = None  # remove categories
table = table.reset_index()
table = table.fillna(0)
table ['Total Score'] = table.female + table.male
table
```

**Output**

```
    job       female    male    Total Score
0   Accountant  358.0   0.0     358.0
1   Engineer    123.0   230.0   353.0
2   Lawyer     320.0    103.0   423.0
3   Manager    294.0    490.0   784.0
4   Sales        0.0    82.0    82.0
5   Waiter     524.0    436.0   960.0
```